# Select less and less records over time?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'd like to write a query or stored procedure to retrieve less and less records over time from a relational database.

Think of this like populating the Google Finance stock chart: The past few days will have all ticks fit the day, and the further you go back, less and less ticks are displayed on each date. All ticks will show for today, 50% of ticks will show for one week ago, 30% for one month ago, and 10% for one year ago. Think of this like a gradient.

Is it possible to achieve this with one query? Or perhaps it would be necessary to use multiple queries? What might this look like?

Note that record ids are non-contiguous (there are gaps), but each record has a timestamp for determining order.

Also note that I am using MySQL.

Here is the structure of my table:

```
quotes
    id
    security_id
    last_price
    bid_price
    ask_price
    date
    timestamp
    trade_volume
    cumulative_volume
    average_volume
    created_at
```

Comment: An example of table structure and data would be great. Otherwise you will probably only get vage suggestions.

Comment: Updated the question with the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for a constant set of records that represent the time-span. You can do so by defining a control date set.

Here's a sample query (doesn't account for weekends and holidays but that can be added):

POPULATE:

```
CREATE TABLE #quotes
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,security_id VARCHAR(50)
    ,last_price FLOAT
    ,bid_price FLOAT
    ,ask_price FLOAT
    ,[date] DATETIME
    ,[timestamp] DATETIME
    ,trade_volume FLOAT
    ,cumulative_volume FLOAT
    ,average_volume FLOAT
    ,created_at DATETIME
)
DECLARE @i int 
set @i = 100000
WHILE @i > 0 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO #quotes (
    security_id
    ,last_price 
    ,bid_price 
    ,ask_price 
    ,[date] 
    ,[timestamp]
    ,trade_volume 
    ,cumulative_volume
    ,average_volume 
    ,created_at

)
values( 'IBM US'
    , 100.00 + RAND()
    , 100.00 + RAND()
    , 100.00 + RAND()
    , DATEADD(MINUTE, -1* @i, GETDATE())
    , DATEADD(MINUTE, -1* @i, GETDATE())
    , 10000000.00 + RAND()*1000000.00
    , 10000000.00 + RAND()*1000000.00
    , 10000000.00 + RAND()*1000000.00
    ,getdate())

set @i= @i-1
END
```

You can change around the time span, but the following will give you around 1000 records that represent the set from start to finish.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @j FLOAT,
    @step FLOAT
set @StartDate = GETDATE()-20
SET @EndDAte = GETDATE()
set @j = 0.0

CREATE TABLE #TimeTable 
(
    IntervalDate DATETIME
)
--say you always want 1000 measures
--use the datediff value to define the step size:
select @step = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)/1000.0

WHILE @j < DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
BEGIN 
    INSERT #TimeTable (IntervalDate) VALUES (DATEADD(minute, @j, @StartDate))
    SET @j = @j+@step
    print @j
END


select security_id
    ,last_price 
    ,bid_price 
    ,ask_price 
    ,[date] 
    ,[timestamp]
    ,trade_volume 
    ,cumulative_volume
    ,average_volume 
    ,created_at 
from #Quotes q
    join #TimeTable t on dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, q.date), 0) = dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, t.IntervalDate), 0)
```